# Unable to modify form in Access when linked to ArcGIS

Tags: ms-access, vba, arcgis

I created a split Access 2010 database with a backend for just tables and the frontend with queries and forms.  The frontend is linked using an OLE DB connection to ArcGIS, which works fine.  When the database connection is connected I am unable to modify my forms but I can update and create queries.

Could this be an issue with having the forms bound to my table query? or is it because I am using a table query for the form?  I don't know how to update my table records from the form without it being bound to the table.

This is also a multiple user database and other users maybe linking this to ArcGIS and might also need to make modifications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the ArcGIS 10.2 help:

> Linked tables in Access are not viewable through an OLE DB connection, although Access queries are available. To use the linked table, create a query in Access that references the linked table and connect to the linked table through the query in the OLE DB connection.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000023000000